# Understanding where clause

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand the `where` clause, the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/where.html) shows me the normal `where` clause:

```
where
    A: Trait + TraitB,
```

But as I start reading code, I start seeing more of

```
where
    A: TraitA,
    A::TraitType: TraitB,
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but here where we're dealing with associate types. Where the type `TraitType` in `TraitA` must implement `TraitB`. Now what does the below mean especially the command followed by a struct?

```
where
    A: TraitA, { StructA { f } }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Correct if i wrong but thats where we dealing with associate types. where the type TraitType in TraitA must implement TraitB.

That is correct.

> now what does the below mean especially the command followed by a struct:
>
> ```
> where
>    A: TraitA, { StructA { f } }
> ```

That's just a function body that returns an instance of `StructA`.  It means the same thing as:

```
where A: TraitA
{
    return StructA {
        f: f
    };
}
```

Except the code in your question uses a trailing expression to return the value instead of an explicit `return` statement.  Trailing expressions are the preferred way to return values in Rust; explicit `return` is usually only used to return early, e.g. out of an `if` branch or a `match` arm.

Comment: Trailing expressions are preferred, but terribly formatted code is not :P

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No argument there!